# Exception while getting data from Service Now using Rest API (Table API)

Tags: java, ssl, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am using ServiceNow Table API - JAVA to fetch data (GET request). I am following the example provided in the below service now wiki link:

URL: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API_Java_Examples#gsc.tab=0

I am getting " java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)  
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)  
  at com.ucas.reports.volumetric.Demo.go(Demo.java:64)  
  at com.ucas.reports.volumetric.Demo.main(Demo.java:31)
```

I am using maven to handle the dependency and using apache httpclient (4.5.3). Below is my code for reference:

```
package com.reports.volumetric;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;  
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;  
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;  
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;  
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;  


import com.reports.util.AppConstants;  

public class Demo {  

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
  go();  
  }  


  private static void go() throws IOException {  
      CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();  
      credsProvider.setCredentials(  
      new AuthScope(new HttpHost(new HttpHost(AppConstants.SNOW_HOST))),  
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials("WebServiceUser", "WebServiceUserPassword"));  
      CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;  
      try {  
          httpclient = HttpClients.custom()  
                      .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)  
                      .build();  
          HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://instance.service-
                            now.com/api/now/table/incident");  
          httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
          System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());  
          CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);  
      try {  
          System.out.println("----------------------------------------");  
          System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());  
          System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));  
        } finally {  
          response.close();  
        }  
  }  finally {  
      httpclient.close();  
   }  
  }  
}
```

I am able to get the data if i open the URL from the browser with the web service credentials. But when i run my java code it throws java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

> UPDATE

I was using Java 1.8 (jdk1.8.0_121). I changed the version to 1.6 (jdk1.6.0_24) and re-ran the above program and I was getting the json output as expected. I am not sure why it is failing in Java 1.8 version.

Below is the ssl debug logs while running in Java 1.8

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2  
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1498393794 bytes = { 12, 120, 234, 134, 188, 168, 18, 119, 116, 190, 203, 67, 203, 117, 140, 58, 11, 37, 238, 63, 195, 158, 126, 45, 223, 152, 145, 239 }  
Session ID:  {}  
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]  
Compression Methods:  { 0 }  
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}  
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]  
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA  
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=instance.service-now.com]  
***  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 194  
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1  
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2  
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error  
main, called closeSocket()  
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false  
Allow legacy hello messages: true  
Is initial handshake: true  
Is secure renegotiation: false  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
%% No cached client session  
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2  
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1498393854 bytes = { 85, 197, 18, 247, 65, 37, 118, 123, 184, 222, 135, 136, 206, 199, 231, 124, 208, 237, 123, 64, 244, 31, 61, 23, 131, 135, 41, 99 }  
Session ID:  {}  
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]  
Compression Methods:  { 0 }  
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}  
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]  
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA  
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=instance.service-now.com]  
***  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 194  
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1  
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2  
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error  
main, called closeSocket()  
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false  
Allow legacy hello messages: true  
Is initial handshake: true  
Is secure renegotiation: false  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1  
%% No cached client session  
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2  
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1498394170 bytes = { 217, 71, 119, 16, 216, 43, 85, 204, 44, 23, 245, 62, 134, 87, 162, 228, 248, 194, 9, 10, 45, 170, 236, 196, 114, 95, 34, 181 }  
Session ID:  {}  
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]  
Compression Methods:  { 0 }  
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}  
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]  
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA  
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=instance.service-now.com]  
***  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 194  
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1  
Exception in thread "main" main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message  
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2  
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error  
main, called closeSocket()  
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)  
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)  
  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)  
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)  
  at com.reports.volumetric.Demo.go(Demo.java:67)  
  at com.reports.volumetric.Demo.main(Demo.java:33)
```

Comment: How long does it take before the SocketException is thrown? Is it immediate, or is it after a few minutes?

Comment: Also... you may try adding the parameter "sysparm_limit=10" to see if smaller result sets behave any differently.

Comment: It takes at least 4 minutes before the SocketException is thrown. I also tried adding the parameter "sysparm_limit=10" but i still get the same exception. I tried calling the service now rest api via browser, postman it is working fine. I also used the below curl command and i am getting the json response:                                                                                                 
      curl https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparam_limit=10 --user username:password

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using a different way to query the API data.
Below code works fine to get incident data from my instance.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

    public class NetClientGet {

        // API Called: https://<instance>.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "https://milind.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                        "<your base64 encoded authorization>");

                if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                            + conn.getResponseCode());
                }

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        (conn.getInputStream())));

                String output;
                System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(output);
                }

                conn.disconnect();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }
```

API called: https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1

Output:
Output from Server ....

{"result":[{"parent":"","made_sla":"false","caused_by":"","watch_list":"","upon_reject":"","sys_updated_on":"2017-03-08 20:16:07","child_incidents":"","hold_reason":"","approval_history":"","skills":"","number":"INC0000001","resolved_by":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441","value":"6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441"},"sys_updated_by":"admin","opened_by":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7","value":"681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7"},"user_input":"","sys_created_on":"2015-07-08 18:24:13","sys_domain":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global","value":"global"},"state":"7","sys_created_by":"pat","knowledge":"false","order":"","calendar_stc":"7937181","closed_at":"2016-12-07 23:10:06","cmdb_ci":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmdb_ci/b0c4030ac0a800090152e7a4564ca36c","value":"b0c4030ac0a800090152e7a4564ca36c"},"delivery_plan":"","cmdb_ci_business_app":"","impact":"1","active":"false","work_notes_list":"","business_service":"","priority":"1","sys_domain_path":"/","rfc":"","time_worked":"","expected_start":"","opened_at":"2016-12-06 23:09:51","business_duration":"1970-01-22 21:46:21","group_list":"","work_end":"","caller_id":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/5137153cc611227c000bbd1bd8cd2005","value":"5137153cc611227c000bbd1bd8cd2005"},"resolved_at":"2017-03-08 19:56:12","approval_set":"","subcategory":"","work_notes":"","short_description":"Can't read email","close_code":"Closed/Resolved by Caller","correlation_display":"","delivery_task":"","work_start":"","assignment_group":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06","value":"d625dccec0a8016700a222a0f7900d06"},"additional_assignee_list":"","business_stc":"1892781","description":"User can't access email on mail.company.com.\n\t\t","calendar_duration":"1970-04-02 20:46:21","close_notes":"Closed before close notes were made mandatory\n\t\t","notify":"1","sys_class_name":"incident","closed_by":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0","value":"9ee1b13dc6112271007f9d0efdb69cd0"},"follow_up":"","parent_incident":"","sys_id":"9c573169c611228700193229fff72400","contact_type":"","incident_state":"7","urgency":"1","problem_id":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/problem/9d3a266ac6112287004e37fb2ceb0133","value":"9d3a266ac6112287004e37fb2ceb0133"},"company":"","reassignment_count":"1","activity_due":"","assigned_to":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/46b87022a9fe198101a78787e40d7547","value":"46b87022a9fe198101a78787e40d7547"},"severity":"1","comments":"","approval":"","sla_due":"","comments_and_work_notes":"","due_date":"","sys_mod_count":"21","reopen_count":"","sys_tags":"","escalation":"0","upon_approval":"","correlation_id":"","location":{"link":"https://.service-now.com/api/now/table/cmn_location/1083361cc611227501b682158cabf646","value":"1083361cc611227501b682158cabf646"},"category":"network"}]}